# Call a function assigned in jQuery Plugin Options

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I made a jQuery plugin. Now i want assign a jQuery animation (with callback) in the options of the jQuery plugin:

```
(function($){  

$.fn.jPl = function(options) {

var $e = $(this);

var defaults = {
    showEffect:     jQuery.noop,
    hideEffect:     jQuery.noop, 
};  

var options = $.extend(defaults, options); 

var onSuccess = function ( ) {

    $e.options.hideEffect ( function () {

        render(function () {

            $e.options.showEffect ( function ( ) {

                if ( waitTime < options.minWait ) waitTime = options.minWait;
                setTimeout ( function ( ) { refreshWall ( ) } , waitTime * 1000 );
                waitTime = 0;

            });


        })

    });

}

}})(JQuery);
```

Call:

```
    $( "#obj" ).jPl ( {

      showEffect: $.fn.showEffect,
      hideEffect: $.fn.clearEffect,

    } ) ;
```

Now i get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: showEffect is not defined

showEffect is defined and when I call it in the Plugin, it works fine.

=================
**Edit**
The showEffect and clearEffect is defined in an other JS File:

```
    (function($) {
      $.fn.clearEffect = function( callback ) {

        return this.each(function() {

          $(this).hide ( function ( ) {


            if (typeof callback == 'function') { // make sure the callback is a function
              callback.call(this); // brings the scope to the callback
            }


          });

        });
      }

      $.fn.showEffect = function( callback ) {

        return this.each(function() {

            $(this).show ( function ( ) {

            if (typeof callback == 'function') { // make sure the callback is a function
              callback.call(this); // brings the scope to the callback
            }


          });

        });

      }
    })(jQuery);
```

I think, it's an Error with calling the function like this: $e.options.showEffect - but i'm not sure.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `showEffect` and `clearEffect` a properties of `$.fn`, not `$`.

Comment: sorry, changed. But get the same Error

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code given, your `showEffect` function exists within the scope of the plugin but not outside the scope of the plugin.

Unless you have another function called `showEffect` that was declared outside the anonymous function used to create the plugin you will get the error you have received.

Answer (score 0):

Your example may be incomplete as I find hard to believe that some code actually works.

`$e.options.showEffect` would not work as options is a local variable; you need to declare this.options instead of var options;

```
var defaults = {
    showEffect:     function,
    hideEffect:     function, 
};
```

function should be replaced with jQuery empty function jQuery.noop, as your version may not work in all browsers

But still, if the first error you get its Uncaught ReferenceError: showEffect is not defined, then i think showEffect its not defined in the same scope you call the plugin, as 
this code throws other errors, but not the one you have :

```
 function showEffect() {
 }

 function clearEffect() {
 }

 $("#obj").jPl ( {

  showEffect: showEffect,
  hideEffect: clearEffect

} ) ;
```

Comment: Hi!
Thank you for your answer!
showEffect and clearEffect are also jquery plugins (i appended them in the main post). i replace null with function, javascript returns an "Unexpected token ," - Exception. 
So I replaced it with jQuery.noop, now I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hideEffect' of undefined
     $e.options.hideEffect ( function () {

but i defined hideEffect in my options (not the defaults)? :(

Thank you :(

Comment: Hi, as i said in my main post options its not accesible as its declared as a local variable. Replace "var options = $.extend(defaults, options); " with "this.options = $.extend(defaults, options); " and it will work; also you shouldn't use $.fn.showEffect :), just $.showEffect; fn is the prototype of the jquery object, you use it only when declaring new functions (plugins)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately that isn't the problem :( I changed it to "this.options = ..." and "$e.options.hideEffect" - but i get the same error: "Object [object Object] has no method 'hideEffect'" - It's strange, but when I replace $e.options.hideEffect with $e.clearEffect (the defined plugin in the oder JS File) - it works. :(